# Number recognition in a randomly generated numeric pad

Tags: python, image, image-recognition, python-tesseract, imagehash

I'm struggling to find a way to precisely extract numbers from a numeric pad. I have tried pytesseract, image.hash and even a code I found that compares characteristics from one image trying to find them in the other image and gives a percentage of similarity.

I'll link some images so you can see what I'm talking about.

Also, I want to clarify, I have also tried to invert the images and use the whitelist in pytesseract but it still wrongly recognizes some numbers (especially the 7 with 1, 8 with 0, 9 with 8, etc).

Thanks in advance.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TerVQ.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ek13.png)

Comment: The 1 and 7 are always going to be tough to separate.  Have you tried doing thresholding to convert to monochrome, which should eliminate the circles?

Comment: yeah, I've tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work as respected. For the problem with the circles, I crop the image I take for every number so the circles don't appear.